# VB6 Winsock Server Connect with WebSocket

Tags: websocket, vb6, winsock

I have a WebSocket created with HTML5 and Javascript, and i'm trying to connect it using Winsock configured in VB6, WebSocket is communicating with the Winsock and WebSocket connection is still in the Connecting stage, and not connecting, seems i have a problem in Handshaking with the WebSocketm. Please help me to find the problem with my code

My vb6 code as bellow

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Winsock1.LocalPort = 6701
    Winsock1.Listen
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectionRequest(Index As Integer, ByVal requestID As Long)
    Winsock1(Index).Close
    Winsock1(Index).Accept requestID

    Dim Packet As String

    With Winsock1(Index)

        Packet = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake" & vbNewLine
        Packet = Packet & "Upgrade: WebSocket" & vbNewLine
        Packet = Packet & "Connection: Upgrade" & vbNewLine
        Packet = Packet & "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=" & vbNewLine

        Data = Empty

        .SendData Packet

     End With
End Sub


Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(Index As Integer, ByVal bytesTotal As    Long)
    Dim sData As String
    Winsock1(Index).GetData sData
    txtText1.Text = sData
End Sub
```

and sample WebScocket html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function connect() {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:6701");
            ws.onopen = function () {
                console.log('open ');
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                console.log("About to receive data");
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                console.log("Message received = " + received_msg);
            };
            ws.onclose = function () {
                // websocket is closed.
                console.log("Connection is closed...");
            };
        };


    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:xx-large" >
    <div>
    <a href="#" onclick="connect()">Click here to start</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or any other way to use WebSocket in Visual Basic 6, please i need a help, (i have fully working C# methods, but some of my required dependencies on the development requirement are only working with VB6)

Comment: You've got a long way to go to start using websockets with VB6. Its something I do on the regular, so I know it can be done, but you're relatively far away and I don't have a tidy package for it. Everything I used to learn about websockets came from documentation (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) and the knowledge translates nicely into other languages as well. All of the data that goes from the web browser to your vb6  web socket server will be masked and unreadable unless you learn how to unframe the data first.

Comment: Up to now, Handshaking and reserving message to VB6 Application has been dona and now i'm struggling with sending a string to web socket from Wnsock (Wnsock1.SendData MessageString), after sending the string to websocket, websocket is disconnecting and error is showing in the console like WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6701/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

cannot even ask a question they saying (You have reached your question limit)

Comment: after that, i trying to send string by converting to byte array
Dim str  As String
'Dim bt() As Byte
'str = tbMsg.Text
'bt = StrToByte(str)

'VoicePrintSocket.SendData bt

Comment: @DilanWickramarathna Did you get the answer