# Convert String to Byte in VB6 with &H81 included in 0th index

Tags: vb6

How to Convert string in to Byte array that contain &H81 in first index if the byte array mybyte(0) with

i need to check in my byte array

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory _
            Lib "kernel32" _
            Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, _
                                   Source As Any, _
                                   ByVal Length As Long)
```

---

```
Private Sub cmdCommand1_Click()
    Dim str  As String
    Dim BT() As Byte

   BT() = StrToByte(tbMsg.Text)

   If BT(0) = &H81 Then
      'MyCode
   End If

End Sub
```

> the   If mybyte(0) = &H81 Then condition is allays getting false

and currently i'm using this string to byte converting method

```
Public Function StrToByte(strInput As String) As Byte()
    Dim lPntr    As Long
    Dim bTmp()   As Byte
    Dim bArray() As Byte

    If Len(strInput) = 0 Then Exit Function
        ReDim bTmp(LenB(strInput) - 1) 'Memory length
        ReDim bArray(Len(strInput) - 1) 'String length
        CopyMemory bTmp(0), ByVal StrPtr(strInput), LenB(strInput)

    For lPntr = 0 To UBound(bArray)

        If bTmp(lPntr * 2 + 1) > 0 Then
            bArray(lPntr) = Asc(Mid$(strInput, lPntr + 1, 1))
        Else
            bArray(lPntr) = bTmp(lPntr * 2)
        End If
    Next lPntr

   StrToByte = bArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A typo I think, it should be:

```
If BT(0) = &H81 Then
```

Not

```
If mybyte(0) = &H81 Then
```

Your code seems to be converting the double byte unicode string into a single byte representation of the string, this will result in garbage for any character with a codepoint > 255.

If thats ok your code is equivalent to the built in:

```
BT() = StrConv(strInput, vbFromUnicode)
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex K, thanks for correct my mistake and I have tried this method and that condition is still false,

Comment: i'm actualy trying to send data to WinSock to WebSocket,, 
Related with my question ,,, if you have any idea about that problem please help me .. :) 

Quastion 2 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537671/send-string-from-vb6-winsock-to-websockets

Comment: and my one of my previous question was this, Questions 1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250260/vb6-winsock-server-connect-with-websocket , not yet answered, by i did pass that part and now i'm stucked at this part, converting data and sending data back to websocket,, according to second question